# Linear approximation to xln(x)

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, lagrange-interpolation

Suppose we need to approximate $f(8.4)$ where  $f(x) = \mathbb{xln(x)}$ by using a **linear polynomial** . We  have the following points as nodes : $x_0=8.1 , x_1 = 8.3 ,  x_2 = 8.6 , x_3 = 8.7$ .

I realize that we can use Lagrange Interpolation to fit a linear polynomial by choosing any two nodal points . But , as I have been given $4$ nodal points , how should I choose the best two points for the approximation (without evaluating $f$ directly at $x = 8.4$ ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a piecewise linear function, making a linear function between each pair of points.  As $8.4$ is between $8.3$ and $8.6$, use those two points.

Comment: I am aware of the fact that piecewise linear function can be used , but our driving force should be to minimize the error in finding f at 8.4 , isn't it ? (Please correct me if I am saying something wrong ) . So , basically if we know f at two nodal points then , we cannot extract more information about f(8.4) from the other two nodal points that we have not used ?

Comment: You can't with a linear function.  For a linear function you are best served by using the two closest points.  If you had data at $8.0,8.3,9.0$ you could argue you should use  the $8.0,8.3$ data, but it is also attractive to use bracketing points.  Extracting information from other points corresponds to using a higher order interpolation.  That is a fine idea, but your question prohibits it.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Also , what are 'bracketing points' ? I haven't heard of it before !

Comment: Bracketing points are ones on opposite sides of the point of interest.  For interpolation, they are usually the ones next to the point of interest.  For 1D root finding they are points where the function is known to have opposite signs, meaning  (assuming it is continuous) there is a root somewhere in between.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is to consider
$$\Phi=\int_{8.1}^{8.7} (x \log(x)-a-bx)^2 \,dx$$ which is equivalent to a linear regression with an infinite number of data points.

Use the fact that, expanding and using integrations by parts
$$I=\int (x \log(x)-a-bx)^2 \,dx$$ $$I=\frac{1}{54} x \left(54 a^2+27 a (2 b x+x)-6 x \log (x) (9 a+6 b x+2 x)+2 \left(9
   b^2+6 b+2\right) x^2+18 x^2 \log ^2(x)\right)$$ Use the bounds to get
$$\Phi=0.6 a^2+a (10.08 b-21.4547)+42.354 b^2-180.332 b+191.97$$ Compute the partial derivatives and set them equal to $0$; this gives two equations for two unknowns $(a,b)$ and the solution would be $\{a= -8.39714,b= 3.12810\}$.

Then, for $x=8.4$, you will get $17.8789$ while the exact value is $17.8771$.

**Edit**

Using exact arithmetic, it is possible to compute the exact values of parameters $a$ and $b$ using the classical least square method for the four data points as well as for the integration. The formulae will not be reported here (too messy); for sure, they are not very different $(0.008\text{%})$. However
$$\frac{\Phi_{ols}}{\Phi_{int}}=2.0414$$

Comment: Never thought it this way ! Can you please suggest some reading on this approach . But , note that that linear approximation yields $17.87833$ which is actually a bit more accurate than this method .

Comment: @John. As I wrote, this is equivalent to the linear regression with an infinite number of data points. Then, the summation is transformed to an integral. Think about it and you will see that it is simple. The result is the best fit over the *entire* range of $x$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct ! I am still a novice learner , so I could not appreciate this fact earlier . Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: @John. Almost every single day, I am still a novice learner too. This is the beauty of mathematics; it is a so vaste domain !